# Why do so many Spanish speakers use the expression "¿Qué pasó?" instead of "¿Qué pasa?" as a greeting?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I was taught that

> ¿Qué pasa?

loosely means *How are things?* or *What's happening?* but I keep hearing

> ¿Qué pasó?

Why?

Comment: In Argentina we never use "¿Qué pasa?" or "¿Qué pasó?" to say hi but "¿Qué tal?", "¿Cómo va?" and, colloquially and mainly among young people, "¿Qué onda?" It comes as a surprise that "¿Qué pasa?" and "¿Qué pasó?" are used as a greeting.

Comment: @Gustavson In Spain, "¿Qué pasa?" is commonly used as a neutral greeting in which you don't really expect any specific answer. I've heard "¿Qué pasó?" in tv movies and series depicting Mexicans.

Comment: Ah, yes, I remember my university friends from Argentina said "Que tal." I think I'll use that one. "Que paso" doesn't make sense to me because it translates as "What happened" and I would think it would be used when someone breaks a leg or I see a terrible traffic accident. "Oh, my God, what happened?" I hear it from Mexicans, so perhaps it's idiomatic. Thanks for the prompt and informative answer.

Comment: Related: ["¿quiubo?, sometimes shortened to just "quiu"](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?quiubo) and ["¿qué úbole?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32678/what-is-the-meaning-of-qu%c3%a9-h%c3%babole)

Answer (score 5):

"¿Qué pasa?" is present tense same as "what is going on?" while "¿qué pasó?" is past tense and translates as "what happened?"

Both are valid ways of asking another person about recent or present events on his life so they both are used as common greetings among many other ways of saying hello in Spanish.

Comment: It's true that "¿Qué pasa?" is a greeting, but "¿Qué pasó"? it's a rethorical question, as @RubioRic pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It is "slang" but as I've lived in different parts of the US I've noticed it has a regional difference, depending on where the Spanish speaking people were from. In Miami, the mostly Cuban born people I worked with in the 1970's all said Que Pasa, but in Arizona and California (and in Sonora Mexico) the Mexican Spanish speakers commonly say Que paso. It is a casual greeting, just as in the US we say "what's happening" and doesn't require a specific response. But if you greeted someone here with "what happened?" they wouldn't recognize it as a greeting, but an odd question.

Similarly, French Speaking Canadians have differences from Parisians. And many countries have regional differences; in different parts of Italy common sayings and pronunciations differ from province to province. Here in the US we have phrases in Boston that wouldn't be recognized in Georgia, and in Texas that wouldn't be understood in Iowa.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué pasó?

So let me clear this up once and for all with a definitive, absolute answer.
I am a second generation Mexican-Mexican American born and raised in San Antonio, Texas. My parents are first generation Mexican Americans who grew up with Español as their first language. Both my parents families are originally from northern Mexico. Monterrey, Saltillo, and Musquiz to be exact. Hence, my credentials.

The pharse "¿Qué pasó?" is a greeting that means "Whats happening?" As in "What's going on?" The typical response can be somethings as simple as "Aye, aquí no mas.", or you can simply respond with "¿Qué pasó?" in turn. You can also respond with a more detailed answer explaining, this is what is happening at the moment, happening in general, or respond with your life story.

This simple greeting "¿Qué pasó?" leaves the recipient of the greeting open to responding in many different ways.

The greeting "¿Qué pasó?" is primarily used throughout south Texas, New Mexico, Arizona, southern California by persons of northern Mexican decent and of course northern Mexico .

Anyway, persons from the above stated regions will know what "¿Qué pasó?" means. If you want to jazz it up a bit you can ask "¿Qué pasó ese?". "¿Qué pasó compañero?" And with close friends "¿Qué pasó cabrón?"

I grew up using these phrases almost everyday of my life and I still use them with family members, close friends and with casual acquaintances who will understand the question.

¡Que le vaya bien amigos!¡Gracias por leer!
I hope this information helps.

Answer (score -3):

All languages have different territorial accents.  The letter O in Spanish or Mexican denotes a male or masculine slant.
Que Paso is a male or masculine accent.
While Que Pasa is a more relaxed accent.
Often different regions speak it differently. West and East regions are different. While also many have migrated to the USA and do not speak original language in the present. They have transformed to new accents and slangs.

Comment: That seems in contradiction to the other answer. Do you have a source which backs it up?

Comment: This doesn't seem at all likely, do you have a source to support this answer? The "pasa" and "pasó" in "¿Qué pasa?" and "¿Qué pasó?" are verbs not nouns and verbs in Spanish don't have grammatical gender, do they? Whereas -a and -ó are common endings for verbs the third person singular in the present tense and in the preterite perfect tense, respectively.